# Does setConnectTimeout not affect the gateway timeout?

Tags: java, timeout, gateway

I'm opening an `HttpUrlConnection` and am setting the connection timeout using its inherited `setConnectTimeout` method, but for one particular URL I'm getting a gateway timeout (a 504).  I don't *mind* getting a gateway timeout as such, but I do object to it taking far longer than the connection timeout that I've set!

Does `setConnectTimeout` have no impact upon the gateway timeout?  I couldn't see another intuitively-named method that I could use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set read timeout by **setReadTimeout**. If you got a 504, it means that the connection is ok, but waiting too long to read something from it.

See more here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout(int)